# Socket.IO Client std::bind - error C2338: tuple index out of bounds

Tags: c++

I am referring example provided on https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-cpp/ to create an Socket.IO Client.

I have created an class which handles all communication via Socket.IO. I am able to connect and send data successfully. I am trying to bind the receive_listener to track incoming message. I am getting the error

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\utility(542): error C2338: tuple index out of bounds
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\utility(559): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tuple_element<0,std::tuple<>>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\functional(1832): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tuple_element<1,std::tuple<sio::event &>>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\tuple(958): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::tuple_element_t<1,std::tuple<sio::event &>>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\tuple(987): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'const tuple_element<_Index,std::tuple<_Rest...>>::type &&std::get(const std::tuple<_Rest...> &&) noexcept' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\type_traits(1871): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::_Is_invocable_r_<void,std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl Socket_IO::* )(const std::string &,const sio::message::ptr &,bool,sio::message::list &),Socket_IO *,const std::_Ph<1> &,const std::_Ph<2> &,const std::_Ph<3> &,const std::_Ph<4> &>&,sio::event&>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\functional(1277): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Is_invocable_r<_Ret,_Fx &,sio::event &>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ret=void,
1>            _Fx=std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl Socket_IO::* )(const std::string &,const sio::message::ptr &,bool,sio::message::list &),Socket_IO *,const std::_Ph<1> &,const std::_Ph<2> &,const std::_Ph<3> &,const std::_Ph<4> &>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\functional(1277): note: see reference to variable template 'const bool conjunction_v<std::negation<std::is_same<std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl Socket_IO::*)(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const &,std::shared_ptr<sio::message> const &,bool,sio::message::list &),Socket_IO *,std::_Ph<1> const &,std::_Ph<2> const &,std::_Ph<3> const &,std::_Ph<4> const &>,std::function<void __cdecl(sio::event &)> > >,std::_Is_invocable_r<void,std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl Socket_IO::*)(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const &,std::shared_ptr<sio::message> const &,bool,sio::message::list &),Socket_IO *,std::_Ph<1> const &,std::_Ph<2> const &,std::_Ph<3> const &,std::_Ph<4> const &> &,sio::event &> >' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\functional(1499): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::_Func_class<_Ret,sio::event &>::_Enable_if_callable_t<_Fx&,std::function<void (sio::event &)>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ret=void,
1>            _Fx=std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl Socket_IO::* )(const std::string &,const sio::message::ptr &,bool,sio::message::list &),Socket_IO *,const std::_Ph<1> &,const std::_Ph<2> &,const std::_Ph<3> &,const std::_Ph<4> &>
1>        ]
```

whenever I add the line

```
this->current_socket->on("message", std::bind(&Socket_IO::receive_listener, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4));
```

The moment I remove the above line the program starts working. However the above line is necessary to bind receive listener to track incoming messages.

```
void Socket_IO::connection_listener(void)
{
    this->current_socket = this->client.socket();
    this->connectionEstablished = true;
    this->current_socket->on("message", std::bind(&Socket_IO::receive_listener, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4)); //The line giving error
    this->sendMessage("Hellowm, World!!! Programing Socket.IO");
}

void Socket_IO::receive_listener(std::string const&name, sio::message::ptr const& data, bool hasAck, sio::message::list &ack_resp)
{
    spdlog::info("Data Recieved : " + data->get_map()["message"]->get_string());
    this->recvDataQueue.push(data->get_map()["message"]->get_string());
}
```

Comment: What's the signature of the function on(), where you register your callback?

Comment: The signature of function on is : void on(std::string const& event_name,event_listener_aux const& func);         where the event_listener_aux  is typedef : std::function<void(const std::string& name,message::ptr const& message,bool need_ack, message::list& ack_message)> event_listener_aux;

Comment: receive_listener does not use any member functions. Does it happen the same when you define it static for the class and simply register is as on("message", Socket_IO::receive_listener)?

Comment: receive_listener has to be a private non-static method as it pushes data in a private data member (std::queue<std::string>) recvDataQueue for where it is used for further processing. The application may have multiple instances (objects) Socket_IO class which would be communicating with different node servers.

Comment: It is more than fine that it is a member function. To set it as static would solely be for debugging purposes.

Comment: I converted receive_listener to static and removed `this` keyword from std::bind yet the problem continues.  
`this->current_socket->on("message", std::bind(&Socket_IO::receive_listener, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4));`  
I changed my receive_listener definition to  
`void Socket_IO::receive_listener(std::string const&name, sio::message::ptr const& data, bool hasAck, sio::message::list &ack_resp)
{
 spdlog::info("Data Recieved : " + data->get_map()["message"]->get_string());
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189793/discussion-between-mikael-h-and-dark-sorrow).

Answer (score 1):

Dark Sorrow added solution, but I wanted to add some explanation.

Looking at the code for Socket.IO, there are two overloads for on(), namely

```
    void on(std::string const& event_name,event_listener const& func);

    void on(std::string const& event_name,event_listener_aux const& func);
```

, with type definitions

```
    typedef std::function<void(const std::string& name,message::ptr const& message,bool need_ack, message::list& ack_message)> event_listener_aux;

    typedef std::function<void(event& event)> event_listener;
```

when doing

```
this->current_socket->on("message", std::bind(&Socket_IO::receive_listener, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4));
```

the compiler does not know which overload to choose since std::bind does not return an object of either event_lister nor event_lister_aux. Somehow the event_lister gets chosen. But the other overload does not have enough arguments, so when std::placeholders::_i are expanding with the tuples, we go out of bound.

Solution is to explicitly tell the compiler which overload you want

```
this->current_socket->on("message", 
    sio::socket::event_listener_aux(
        std::bind(&Socket_IO::receive_listener, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4)
));
```

Now we have the workaround. But we should not be happy, since the syntax for std::bind is confusing (member function pointer, std::placeholders::_i, ...).

Better to use a lambda here, eventhough the argument list if long

```
this->current_socket->on("message", 
    sio::socket::event_listener_aux([this](std::string const& name, sio::message::ptr const& data, bool hasAck, sio::message::list &ack_resp)
     { 
         receive_listener(name, data, hasAck, ack_resp); 
     }
);
```

. This is easier to understand than std::bind as it is closer to normal function definition.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by passing `sio::socket::event_listener_aux` variable to the overloaded `on` method instead of direct bind.

```
sio::socket::event_listener_aux event_listener_aux
this->event_listener_aux = std::bind(&Socket_IO::receive_listener, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4);
this->current_socket->on("message", event_listener_aux);
```

or

```
this->current_socket->on("message", sio::socket::event_listener_aux(std::bind(&Socket_IO::receive_listener, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4)));
```